# How do I stop executing a loop in this JavaScript if else code?

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code as a practice for Javascript in which it's used for a web-page as a logging in kind of system.  It's simple - you type in the username and password, and if it's correct - then it works.  But what's giving me the problem is the part of the code when the information is wrong, it should send an alert and allow the user to try again, and then send another alert.  But what happens instead is that when a user writes wrong info, the alert just keeps on repeating without letting the user try again, until it goes down to 0.

How do I edit the code so the user can try putting in the information again after each loop (attempt--)?

```js
var attempt = 3;
var objects = [
    {
        username: "Marko",
        password: "123"
    },
    {
        username: "Pera",
        password: "123"
    },
    {
        username: "Nikola",
        password: "123"
    }
]

function clearFields() {
    document.getElementById("username").value = "";
    document.getElementById("password").value = "";
}

function validate() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    for(i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        if(username == objects[i].username && password == objects[i].password) {
            alert("You are logged in successfully, " + username);
            window.location = "logovanje.html";
            return false;
        }
        else {
            attempt--;
            alert("Wrong information, you have " + attempt + " attempts left!");  
            {
            if (attempt == 0) {
                document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: try `return` or `break` when your condition is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to move the else-statement outside of the for-loop, because as it is now, you are decreasing the number of attempts and showing alerts for every name in `objects`.

Like this:

```
function validate() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    for(i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        if(username == objects[i].username && password == objects[i].password) {
            alert("You are logged in successfully, " + username);
            window.location = "logovanje.html";
            return false;
        }
    }
    attempt--;
    alert("Wrong information, you have " + attempt + " attempts left!"); 
    if (attempt == 0) {
        document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

That way, if the input is correct, the function will return and stop executing, else it will throw the alert and decrease the attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Use `return;` or `break;` to stop executing loop ;)

Comment: The problem with his code is rather, that he has a part of it inside the loop, which should actually be outside of it.